# Visual Studio Debugging With Sitecore opens file from Website folder not solution folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sitecore

I have a Sitecore set up where my Sitecore Website folder and my visual studio solution are separate. I run the project in full IIS, so to debug I attach to the process. But, for stepping through code the debugger wants the file from the Sitecore Website folder, not the visual studio project, making actual debugging very difficult. I assume this is some sort of visual studio setting?

Comment: How do you deploy your code in visual studio to your sitecore website? you need to make sure to include the.pdb files too in the deployment

Comment: Did you deploy in Release mode or Debug mode? Also check your web config is set to debug=true

Comment: pdb files already there. Enabling debug did not fix the problem.

Comment: Are you deploying with Web One Click Publishing? Have you done a full Rebuild and then deploy to the IIS.

Comment: No, Im deploying with TDS.

Comment: TDS doesn't deploy pdb files, I don't think? If you copy the dll and pdb from your build output to the website, does it work as expected?

Comment: No, I tried that. Its still weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually working as designed. Once you build your solution, it will build the solution and deploy the website to the location that you have selected. Since you are using full IIS, and you attach to the w3p process it will debug that process and not the solution itself.

One item to be cautious of is to ensure that you don't leave any files open that you have breakpoints in and make changes to them. You will want to make changes to the files in your Source Controlled files and not your IIS files.

If you are not using TDS, I would highly recommend ysing TDS also.

Comment: I am using TDS, How do I open a file in the IIS process to add a breakpoint? If I make a change, I need to rebuild to get the change to the IIS version?

Comment: If you do make a change to the cshtml file for example, You will have to rebuild and the changes will be deployed the the website folder you set in TDS. Once you attach to the process, make you are breakpoint in the file that is in your solution and not the one in IIS.  Visual Studio is smart enough to open the one in IIS to step into it so you can see your values. Just be sure to not make changes to the IIS file because they will not be propagated back to your solution.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: No, that is exactly what is happening, I just didnt understand what was going on till you explained it.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you out. Good Luck Sitecoreing!